# Generic method to print map of different object types with same name belongs to different classes

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to write a generic method to print map of different object types with same name belongs to different classes :

```
private<T> void print(T obj) {
    //Some proecssing on obj.keySet()
    obj.getMapOfObjects().values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

for 2 classes B and C, as follows.

```
 public class B implements A {
    private Map<Object, List<String>> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void setMapOfObjects(Map<Object, List<String>> mapOfObjects) {
        this.mapOfObjects = mapOfObjects;
    }
    
    public Map<Object, List<String>> getMapOfObjects() {
        return mapOfObjects;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class C implements A {

    private Map<Integer, List<String>> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<>();

    public void setMapOfObjects(Map<Integer, List<String>> mapOfObjects) {
        this.mapOfObjects = mapOfObjects;
    }
    
    public Map<Integer, List<String>> getMapOfObjects() {
        return mapOfObjects;
    }
}
```

A does not have getMapOfObjects() method as return types are different.

I am getting exception on line obj.getMapOfObjects().values() as "method getMapOfObjects() undefined on type T".
I want to understand whether I can write above method by the use of generics or functions in java 8 and if yes then how to write?

Comment: Can you change `A`, `B` or `C` at all?

Comment: Just add `Map<?, List<String>> getMapOfObjects();` to the interface `A`. Implementing classes can have a more specific return type, that’s no problem.

Comment: @Sweeper, I can not change interface A at all, But I can remove class C and use class B as Object is above Integer.

Comment: @Holger I can not change interface A at all, But I can remove class C and use class B as Object is above Integer. But I just wanted to check without changing if I can do that, using class B will be my last option.

Comment: You could make the accessor method a parameter, `private <T> void print(T obj, Function<T, Map<?, List<String>> getter) { … }`, to be invoked as `print(b, B::getMapOfObjects)` or `print(c, C::getMapOfObjects)`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know what `<T>` is in that first method. What if it is an instance of `String`, which does not have a `getMapOfObjects` method? You have to specify a type for `<T>`.

You know that `<T>` should be an instance of `A` (am I correct in this?), so you can fix the compiler error by specifying this like so:

```java
private <T extends A> void print(T obj) {
    // Some proecssing on obj.keySet()
    obj.getMapOfObjects().values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

Comment: This will only work if `A` does have a method `getMapOfObjects()`